# Customizing ABP6 angular Login Form

Tags: abp

I would like to customize my ABP 6 (Angular) Login page. I couldn't find any helpful documentation apart from [this](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/2.9/How-To/Customize-Login-Page-MVC) old version. I upated my header section code as below

```
@page
@using Volo.Abp.Account.Settings
@using Volo.Abp.Settings
@model MyApp.LoginModels.CustomLoginModel
@inherits Volo.Abp.Account.Web.Pages.Account.AccountPageModel
```

The rest of the coe is as per the documentation. But it throws an error as `CS0115 'Pages_Account_Login.ExecuteAsync()': no suitable method found to override  MyApp.HttpApi.Host  C:\projects\App\MyApp\app\src\MyApp.HttpApi.Host\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Pages_Account_Login_cshtml.g.cs 37  Active` .

I have updated my code a bit to follow [this](https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples/blob/master/Authentication-Customization/src/Acme.BookStore.Web/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml) url. The login page appears to be loading but its not respecting the 'LoginModel' inheritance. The login button click just doesn't do anything.  I'm using OpenIdDict for login and may be this is what causing the issue.    [image: login Page]

Any assistance would be much appreciated

Comment: If this helps you a little: https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples/blob/master/Authentication-Customization/src/Acme.BookStore.Web/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml

Comment: @Kalves, Thanks for sharing this. I have updated my post with some additional information after  following this document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to implement the custom login is to download the ABP [source code](https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples/tree/master/Authentication-Customization/src/Acme.BookStore.Web/Pages/Account) and copy the relevant page contents from Pages/Account to our local solution. I have downloaded the files as per the image to implement the custom login.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not angular it is MVC and it stores in [AccountModule](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Modules/Account) in the documentation describes how to customize via get-source can you please check it

Comment: Thanks @Masum ULU, I have downloaded  the ABP source code and copied the account pages. It all worked as expected .